# Programmatic process substitution in bash

Tags: command-line, bash

As one can found in the docs, the `head <(yes) <(yes n)` will first substitute `<(yes)` and `<(yes n)` with a temporary filename, pointing to pipe which will produce the `yes` or `yes no` respectively output while being read, so the output will be ten `y` and ten `n` chars.

However, the following will not work:

```
head $(echo "<(yes) <(yes n)")                                                      
head: cannot open '<(yes)' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open '<(yes' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open 'n)' for reading: No such file or directory
```

How to overcome this issue and get command to work with `echo` and any other generated process substitution?

Comment: You're going to have to resort to `eval`

Comment: This seems like an overcomplicated and fragile way to do ... something. I suspect there's a better way to do it. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Your command with the quotes won't work, because the process substitution symbols retain their literal value when quoted.

You would think that

```
head $(echo <(yes) <(yes n))
```

would work, but this also fails with the message:

```
head: cannot open '/dev/fd/63' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open '/dev/fd/62' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I believe that the reason for this is that the head command is invoked after the echo command has already completed, so the temporary file descriptors have already been deleted by the time the `head` command is run.

Add some more details to your question exactly what you are trying to do, maybe there is a solution that isn't apparent from this minimal example.